# Property from @ViewChild does not update in Parent Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component that creates instances of the child component via a *ngFor. In my child component I have two properties that I need to use in the parent component.

When the properties get Updated once, the parent gets the update, but when there is a secund update, the values of the properties stay the same in the parent component.

Here is my parent component :

```js
    @Component({
    selector: 'app-events-feed',
    templateUrl: './events-feed.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./events-feed.component.css']
    })
    export class EventsFeedComponent implements OnInit {

    private events: Events[];
    participation: Participations;
    leaveAnyway: string;
    iconSport: string;
    @ViewChild(DetailsEventsComponent) details: DetailsEventsComponent;

    constructor() { }
     saveChanges(ev: Events): void {
    let dateEvenement=new Date(ev.dateEvent);
    dateEvenement.setHours(this.details.hourBegin.getHours());
    dateEvenement.setMinutes(this.details.hourBegin.getMinutes());
    }
```

Html code:

```html
     <mat-list *ngFor="let ev of events">
    <div id="eventContainer">    
      <app-details-events [event]="ev"></app-details-events>
    </div>
    </mat-list>
```

Here is the Child Component:

```js
      @Component({
       templateUrl: './details-events.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./details-events.component.css']
      })
      export class DetailsEventsComponent implements OnInit {
      ngOnInit(): void {

      }

      @Input() event: Events;

      hourBegin: Date;
      dateEnd: Date;
      }
```

Html code:

```html
         <tr>
        <td class=time >
          <mat-label>Begin</mat-label>
          <igx-time-picker id="begin" [(ngModel)]="hourBegin" format="HH:mm" [vertical]="true" [disabled]=!event.isAdmin>
          </igx-time-picker>
        </td>
        <td class=time>
          <mat-label>End</mat-label>
          <igx-time-picker id="end" [(ngModel)]="dateEnd" format="HH:mm" [vertical]="true" [disabled]=!event.isAdmin > 
          </igx-time-picker>
        </td>
```

The first time when I change the time via the TimePicker (in Child component), the value is correctly received in the parent component. But when I try again to change the time in the time picker, even if the view changes, the model does not. I'm new to Angular so maybe it's very obvious and I did not do it correctly?

Thanks to those who'll read and maybe answer. If you think needing more explanations/code to understand the problem, tell me.

Have a nice day,

Lio

Comment: Where are you change the `event` property in child component?

Comment: Move the logic from `constructor` to `AfterViewInit`; you need to wait for the view to be initialized before you can access your `@ViewChild`

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild

Comment: It's not the problem, the view is correctly intialized. The property just fail to update

Comment: Asim, I don't change the event property, If I did it correctly, the event property is changed via two-way binding

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found my answer. The property did not changes because I had to use @ViewChildren (since my child component is "instantiate" several time with *ngFor) instead of @ViewChild.

In the ngFor, I had to add an index to access my viewChildren via an index. If someone wants to see the code, juste ask, I can share.